# MultiItem ListGrid filtering

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-rpc, listgrid

I'm currently setting up a `ListGrid` with filters, but am having problems in implementing a filter for fields with multiple items selection.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve:

I have a `ListGrid` with these values:

```
_________________
|Fruits Selected|
|_______________|
|Apple          |
|Apple,Orange   |
|Orange         |
|_______________|
```

When I try to filter and select Orange in my "Multi-Item Filter" I expect to see this on my grid:

```
_________________
|Fruits Selected|
|_______________|
|Apple,Orange   |
|Orange         |
|_______________|
```

But instead, I only see this:

```
_________________
|Fruits Selected|
|_______________|
|Orange         |
|_______________|
```

Am I interpreting the expected output wrong? If so, is there a way that I can customize the way that multiple items filter is handled?

Another thing, I'm using `GenericGwtRpcDataSource` from this forums. Hopefully this is not an issue.

Here's a sample code as requested:
**DataSource**

```
public class FruitLocalDS extends DataSource {

private static FruitLocalDS instance = null;

public static FruitLocalDS getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new FruitLocalDS("supplyItemLocalDS");
    }
    return instance;
}

public FruitLocalDS(String id) {
    setID(id);

    DataSourceEnumField fruitNameField = new DataSourceEnumField(
            "fruitNames", "Fruit Name");
    fruitNameField.setMultiple(true);
    fruitNameField.setValueMap("Apple", "Guyabano", "Pineapple", "Orange",
            "Grapes");

    setFields(fruitNameField);
    setClientOnly(true);
    setTestData(Fruit.getDummyRecords());
}}
```

**ListGridRecord**:

```
public class Fruit  extends ListGridRecord {

public Fruit(String[] fruitNames) {
    setFruitNames(fruitNames);
}

public void setFruitNames(String[] fruitNames) {
    setAttribute("fruitNames", fruitNames);
}

public String getFruitName() {
    return getAttribute("fruitNames");
}

public static Fruit[] getDummyRecords() {
    return new Fruit[] {
            new Fruit(new String[]{"Orange"}), 
            new Fruit(new String[]{"Apple", "Orange"}),
            new Fruit(new String[]{"Guyabano","Orange"}),
            new Fruit(new String[]{"Pineapple","Orange"}),
    };
}}
```

**EntryPoint**:

```
public class MultiItemTest implements EntryPoint {
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final DataSource dataSource = FruitLocalDS.getInstance();

    ListGrid listGrid = new ListGrid();
    listGrid.setWidth(1000);
    // listGrid.setAutoFitData(Autofit.VERTICAL);
    listGrid.setHeight(224);
    listGrid.setDataPageSize(50);
    listGrid.setDataSource(dataSource);
    listGrid.setShowFilterEditor(true);
    listGrid.setCanEdit(true);
    listGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
    listGrid.setEditEvent(ListGridEditEvent.DOUBLECLICK);

    listGrid.setShowRowNumbers(true);
    listGrid.setFilterOnKeypress(true);
    listGrid.setFetchDelay(1);

    listGrid.draw();
}}
```

When you try selecting 'Orange' in the filter it will only show:

```
Orange
```

what I expect is:

```
Apple,Orange
Guyabano,Orange
Orange
Pineapple, Orange
```

Comment: It's working perfectly on my side. Can you show some code?

Comment: I'll try to create the most trivial code example and post back. Thanks for replying. Anyway, are you using GWT RPC as well?

Comment: I'm also using GWT RPC.